# How to know if a thread is waiting on an EventWaitHandle

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm using an `EventWaitHandle` to block a thread temporarily using `WaitOne()`. I'd like to be able to observe the fact that the WaitHandle is being waited on by just one thread.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Give more context about what you're planning to do with this information, may be better way to do that!

Comment: Testing multithreaded code. There are moments where a looping thread waits and I want to use that opportunity to do some work that eventually Sets the wait handle

Comment: The problem with multi-threading is that often, by the time you know the answer, it is no longer correct. E.g. between observing that a `WaitHandle` is being waited on by just one thread and *acting* on that information, another thread could start waiting on that same handle.